# Info bubble/text in a shiny interface

Tags: r, shiny

Is it possible to have info bubble/text to be displayed for when hover over certain text or UI elements in a shiny UI?

If not possible with the `shiny` package, what kind of html/javascript object could I have rendered with `renderUI()` to have such info text?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joe Cheng has written a help-popup function

https://gist.github.com/jcheng5/5913297

From Claude Boivin on the shiny help list:

```
div(class="row-fluid",
      div(class="span8",h4("subject")),
div(class="span1",helpPopup("help_title,includeHTML("www/help_entrer_fait.html"),placement='bottom',trigger='click'))
```

Comment: This works but I can't have the icon question sign to be displayed. This makes the popover unlikely to be  found by the user..

Comment: I got the icon by changing `tags$i(class="icon-question-sign")` into `icon("question")` in Joe Cheng's code.

Comment: Good to know. Maybe you could add the info to the cited source.

Comment: Thanks @DieterMenne. The help-popup function is however not working when defining it in server.R via renderUI and calling it with uiOutput in der ui.R ... does anyone have a fix for this? Thanks